In a finite field extension $L/K$, is it true that the order of Selmer group $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$ does not decrease?
Let $E/K$ be a fixed elliptic curve over nuber field $K$.
Let $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$ be a Selmer group of $E/K$.
In a finite field extension $L/K$, is it true that the order of $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$ does not decrease?
I think there is no appriori reason that Selmer grouop does not decrease because tosor may have rational points by field extension.
But I cannt find even one counterexamole of small Selmer group under quadratic field extension calculated by following code.

K:=QuadraticField(2); A:=EllipticCurve([K!0,0,0,17,0]);
Sel2:=TwoSelmerGroup(A); Sel2;

